# AFNetworking multipartFormRequestWithMethod works with simulator but not with device

Tags: php, ios, web-services, afnetworking

I try to post image data to my web service using the AFNetworking framework. When running my app with the simulator everything is fine but when i run the app on an iPad, the web service doesn't receive any image data ($_FILES returns nil). Could this be a bug in AFNetworking?

client code:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)POSTRequestForImage:(NSString *)imagePath ForPrepfile:(NSString *)objectId 
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]);
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[imagePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if (imageData == nil) {
        NSLog(@"no data");
    }
    NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageName, @"filename", objectId, @"objectId", nil];
    NSLog(@"imagename: %@", imageName);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"images" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:imageName mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];
    NSLog(@"picture request fileurl: %@", url);
    return request;
}
```

PHP-script using SLIM framework:

```
$app->post('/images', function () use ($app) {
    $pa = new PrepAppDB();
    $out = $app->request()->post();

    // file upload
    $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fileName))
   {
    $result = $pa->updateRow('image', $out);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($result);
   } else {
     sendResponse(400, 'fail');
   }

});
```

I appreciate any help!

-------------------------EDIT-------------------------------

I tested if `$_FILES` is empty which is not the case. When sending the picture via iPad i get the filename through "$_FILES['image']['name']" but the other variables are empty.
I also tested the image data which i append to my request in `appendPartWithFileData:` and it seems to be OK too.
I really don't have a clue... is nobody able to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me... the problem was the image size which was too large on the iPad so the server didn't accept it ;-)